# ssh connection to the aws is working but inbound github cl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, networking, ssh, inbound

ssh connection to the aws is working but inbound github clone I got this message

```
Failed to connect to github.com port 1080: Connection timed out
```

> Dec 12 03:51:11 ip-172-31-18-207
>   amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[1282]: 2019-12-12 03:51:11 ERROR
>   Health ping failed with error - EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance
>   role found Dec 12 03:51:11 ip-172-31-18-207
>   amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[1282]: caused by: EC2MetadataError:
>   failed to make EC2Metadata request Dec 12 03:51:11 ip-172-31-18-207
>   amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[1282]: caused by:

which one should I check

Comment: What do you mean by inbound github clone? Are you using git clone from the ssh on ec2 instance?

Comment: git clone from ec2.I can not use any pip or git clone.

Comment: seems you're instance doesn't have internet access. If you want to make it private attach a NAT gateway to your subnet.